# zheev giving wrong eigenvalues (checked against zgeev and numpy.linalg.eig)

Tags: c++, fortran, lapack, lapacke

Tinkering with linalg libraries, I tried to get a diagonalisation routine for hermitian matrices up and running in c++ using LAPACKE

I followed [this](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/lapacke_zheev_row.c.htm) example to use ZHEEV, and then checked against some other methods, specifically numpy's eig and LAPACK(E)'s zgeev. I didn't want to use intel's own-brand stuff so I avoided MKL and just went for straight LAPACKE, but the majority of the code is the same as in the example.

For clarity, I see no reason why the **ge**neral z**ge**ev shouldn't be able to handle the specific case of a **he**rmitian matrix, even if z**he**ev is optimised.

Here's the c++

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lapacke.h>

//Parameters 
#define N 4
#define LDA N
#define lint lapack_int
#define ldcmplex lapack_complex_double

//Auxiliary routines prototypes 
extern void print_matrix( char* desc, lint m, lint n, ldcmplex* a, lint lda         );
extern void print_rmatrix( char* desc, lint m, lint n, double* a, lint lda         );

//Main program 
int main()
  {
    //Locals 
    lint n = N, lda = LDA, info;
  ;
    //Local arrays 
    double wr[N];
    ldcmplex ah[LDA*N] = { 
           { 9.14,  0.00}, { 0.00,  0.00}, { 0.00,  0.00}, { 0.00,  0.00},
           {-4.37,  9.22}, {-3.35,  0.00}, { 0.00,  0.00}, { 0.00,  0.00},
           {-1.98,  1.72}, { 2.25,  9.51}, {-4.82,  0.00}, { 0.00,  0.00},
           {-8.96,  9.50}, { 2.57, -2.40}, {-3.24, -2.04}, { 8.44,  0.00}
    };
  ; 
    //Executable statements 
    printf( "LAPACKE_zheev (row-major, high-level) Example Program                         Results\n" )    ;
  ; 
    //Print martix 
    print_matrix( "Input Matrix", n, n, ah, lda );
  ; 
    //Solve eigenproblem  
    info = LAPACKE_zheev( LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'V', 'L', n, ah, lda, wr );
  ; 
    //Check for convergence 
    if( info > 0 ) {
            printf( "zheev algorithm failed to compute eigenvalues.\n" );
            exit( 1 );
    }
  ; 
    //Print eigenvalues 
    print_rmatrix( "zheev Eigenvalues", 1, n, wr, 1 );
  ; 
    //Print eigenvectors 
    print_matrix( "Eigenvectors (stored columnwise)", n, n, ah, lda );
  ; 
    //Local arrays 
    ldcmplex wc[N];
    ldcmplex ag[LDA*N] = {
      { 9.14,  0.00}, {-4.37, -9.22}, {-1.98, -1.72}, {-8.96, -9.50},
      {-4.37,  9.22}, {-3.35,  0.00}, { 2.25, -9.51}, { 2.57,  2.40},
      {-1.98,  1.72}, { 2.25,  9.51}, {-4.82,  0.00}, {-3.24,  2.04},
      {-8.96,  9.50}, { 2.57, -2.40}, {-3.24, -2.04}, { 8.44,  0.00},
    };
  ; 
    //Executable statements 
    printf( "LAPACKE_zgeev (row-major, high-level) Example Program Results\n" );
  ; 
    //Print martix 
    print_matrix( "Input Matrix", n, n, ag, lda );
  ; 
    //Solve eigenproblem  
    info = LAPACKE_zgeev( LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'N', 'V', n, ag, lda, wc, 0, lda, 0, lda);
  ; 
    //Check for convergence 
    if( info > 0 ) {
            printf( "zgeev algorithm failed to compute eigenvalues.\n" );
            exit( 1 );
    }
  ; 
    //Print eigenvalues 
    print_matrix( "zgeev Eigenvalues", 1, n, wc, 1);
  ;
    //Print eigenvectors 
    print_matrix( "Eigenvectors (stored columnwise)", n, n, ag, lda );
    exit( 0 );
  }

//Auxiliary routine: printing a matrix 
void print_matrix( char* desc, lint m, lint n, ldcmplex* a, lint lda ) {
        lint i, j;
        printf( "\n %s\n", desc );
        for( i = 0; i < m; i++ ) {
                for( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
                        printf( " (%6.2f,%6.2f)", creal(a[i*lda+j]),     cimag(a[i*lda+j]) );
                printf( "\n" );
        }
}

//Auxiliary routine: printing a real matrix 
void print_rmatrix( char* desc, lint m, lint n, double* a, lint lda ) {
        lint i, j;
        printf( "\n %s\n", desc );
        for( i = 0; i < m; i++ ) {
                for( j = 0; j < n; j++ ) printf( " %6.2f", a[i*lda+j] );
                printf( "\n" );
        }
}
```

compiled with

```
g++ diag.cc -L /usr/lib/lapack/ -llapacke -lcblas -o diag.out
```

The only nonstandard packages being `liblapacke-dev`, and `libcblas-dev`, installed via `apt-get install`. What could possibly go wrong?

The output is

```
LAPACKE_zheev (row-major, high-level) Example Program Results

 Input Matrix
 (  9.14,  0.00) (  0.00,  0.00) (  0.00,  0.00) (  0.00,  0.00)
 ( -4.37,  9.22) ( -3.35,  0.00) (  0.00,  0.00) (  0.00,  0.00)
 ( -1.98,  1.72) (  2.25,  9.51) ( -4.82,  0.00) (  0.00,  0.00)
 ( -8.96,  9.50) (  2.57, -2.40) ( -3.24, -2.04) (  8.44,  0.00)

 zheev Eigenvalues
 -18.96 -12.85  18.78  30.71

 Eigenvectors (stored columnwise)
 (  0.16,  0.00) (  0.57,  0.00) ( -0.73,  0.00) (  0.35,  0.00)
 (  0.26, -0.81) (  0.17, -0.25) (  0.22, -0.38) (  0.06, -0.02)
 (  0.29,  0.27) ( -0.11, -0.30) ( -0.26, -0.42) ( -0.50, -0.50)
 ( -0.21,  0.23) (  0.50, -0.49) (  0.18, -0.09) ( -0.33,  0.51)

LAPACKE_zgeev (row-major, high-level) Example Program Results

 Input Matrix
 (  9.14,  0.00) ( -4.37, -9.22) ( -1.98, -1.72) ( -8.96, -9.50)
 ( -4.37,  9.22) ( -3.35,  0.00) (  2.25, -9.51) (  2.57,  2.40)
 ( -1.98,  1.72) (  2.25,  9.51) ( -4.82,  0.00) ( -3.24,  2.04)
 ( -8.96,  9.50) (  2.57, -2.40) ( -3.24, -2.04) (  8.44,  0.00)

 zgeev Eigenvalues
 ( 25.51,  0.00) (-16.00, -0.00) ( -6.76,  0.00) (  6.67,  0.00)

 Eigenvectors (stored columnwise)
 ( 25.51,  0.00) ( -0.00,  0.00) (  0.00,  0.00) (  0.00, -0.00)
 (  0.00,  0.00) (-16.00, -0.00) (  0.00, -0.00) (  0.00, -0.00)
 (  0.00,  0.00) (  0.00,  0.00) ( -6.76,  0.00) ( -0.00, -0.00)
 (  0.00,  0.00) (  0.00,  0.00) (  0.00,  0.00) (  6.67,  0.00)
```

I tried using the Upper triangle, filling the matrix and various other fixes. Same results each time.

I'm suspicious of the `#define ldcmplex lapack_complex_double` macro, but all the [documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/d9a/group__complex16_h_eeigen_ga70c041fd19635ff621cfd5d804bd7a30.html#ga70c041fd19635ff621cfd5d804bd7a30) I can find says I should be using a double complex, so I'm a bit lost. Anyway, if that was the problem, why would zgeev work?

Anyway, here's the python check script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from numpy import linalg as li
import numpy as np

mat=np.array([
[   9.14 + 0.00j,  0.00 + 0.00j,  0.00 + 0.00j,  0.00 +0.00j],
[  -4.37 + 9.22j, -3.35 + 0.00j,  0.00 + 0.00j,  0.00 +0.00j],
[  -1.98 + 1.72j,  2.25 + 9.51j, -4.82 + 0.00j,  0.00 +0.00j],
[  -8.96 + 9.50j,  2.57 - 2.40j, -3.24 - 2.04j,  8.44 +0.00j]])
mat[0]=np.conj(mat[:,0])
mat[1]=np.conj(mat[:,1])
mat[2]=np.conj(mat[:,2])
mat[3]=np.conj(mat[:,3])

mat=np.matrix(mat)

w, v = li.eig(mat)

print w
print v
```

It agrees with zgeev (up to some rounding/machine errors). The result is also confirmed by the intel tutorial linked above. The zheev method is clearly in a minority of one, I just don't know why.

I've tried this on a couple of machines:

```
Linux parabox 4.8.0-52-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 28 13:28:50 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Linux glass 4.10.0-21-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 28 16:14:22 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome, please be sure to take the [Tour] and read thi gist of [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: People closing and downvoting, which code are you missing? I can see everything is there. The results are there, the behaviour is explained. You just need to actually read what's written in the question.

Comment: Alright -- I have reproduced your results, but with `-lsatlas` where you have `-lcblas`.  Just to restate your question so that I understand you:  "`ZGEEV` should return the same results as `ZHEEV`, but it's not."  Correct?

Comment: Nope, belay that.  ZHEEV eigenvalues are: `-16.00  -6.76   6.67  25.51` on my system.  Out of order, but still the same as ZGEEV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `-cblas` with `-blas` in the compile line solves the issue.

The cblas package must have a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get when I run your python script:

```
$ ./diag.py
[ 25.51400517 +1.20330583e-15j -16.00474647 -2.91871119e-15j
  -6.76497015 -6.59630730e-16j   6.66571145 +1.54590036e-16j]
[[ 0.69747489+0.j          0.21857873+0.26662122j  0.47736933+0.26449375j     -0.02829581-0.30988089j]
 [-0.21578745+0.28003172j  0.69688890+0.j         -0.14143627-0.2852389j       0.24437193-0.47778739j]
 [-0.14607303-0.08302697j -0.01445974-0.60818924j 0.44678181+0.26546077j       0.57583205+0.j        ]
 [-0.34133591+0.49376693j  0.15930699-0.00061647j  0.57507627+0.j             -0.45823952+0.2713093j ]]
```

I don't know what that's supposed to match.  The eigenvalues match, but not the eigenvectors.

Comment: Your output matches zgeev's output for the eigenvalues. Eigenvectors are not important for my question. This shows that pythons eig() and LAPACKE's zgeev match, but zheev doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to deal with `ZGEEV()` and stumbled on this issue. On this rather old system (Ubuntu 14.04), with BLAS 3 backed LAPACK, the results from this sample were also not matching to the expected.

So it turned out the culprit in my case was the initialization of the `lapack_complex_double` matrix. Instead of doing it inline, as is in the original sample, I opted for reading it into a `double[2]` type and then reinitializing it into `lapack_complex_double` using the added `set_matrix()` function.

Additionally, for proper output of the eigen vectors from `ZGEEV`, a `wgr` array should be passed to it, and subsequently printed out.

Below is the updated source code and its output. Hope this would be useful for someone else exploring the `LAPACKE_zgeev` and `LAPACKE_zheev` functions (not much documentation still).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lapacke.h>

//Parameters
#define N 4
#define LDA N
#define lint lapack_int
#define ldcmplex lapack_complex_double

typedef struct double2 {
  double v[2];
} double2_t;


//Auxiliary routines prototypes
extern void print_matrix( char* desc, lint m, lint n, ldcmplex* a, lint lda);
extern void print_rmatrix( char* desc, lint m, lint n, double* a, lint lda);
extern void set_matrix(lapack_int n, lapack_complex_double* a, lapack_int lda, double2_t *a2);

//Main program
int main()
  {
    //Locals
    lint n = N, lda = LDA, info;
  ;
    //Local arrays
    double wr[N];
    ldcmplex ah[LDA*N] = {0};
    double2_t ah2[LDA*N] = {
           { 9.14,  0.00}, { 0.00,  0.00}, { 0.00,  0.00}, { 0.00,  0.00},
           {-4.37,  9.22}, {-3.35,  0.00}, { 0.00,  0.00}, { 0.00,  0.00},
           {-1.98,  1.72}, { 2.25,  9.51}, {-4.82,  0.00}, { 0.00,  0.00},
           {-8.96,  9.50}, { 2.57, -2.40}, {-3.24, -2.04}, { 8.44,  0.00}
    };
  ;
    //Executable statements
    set_matrix(n, ah, lda, ah2);
    printf( "LAPACKE_zheev (row-major, high-level) Example Program Results\n" )    ;
  ;
    //Print martix
    print_matrix( "Input Matrix", n, n, ah, lda );
  ;
    //Solve eigenproblem
    info = LAPACKE_zheev( LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'V', 'L', n, ah, lda, wr );
  ;
    //Check for convergence
    if( info > 0 ) {
            printf( "zheev algorithm failed to compute eigenvalues.\n" );
            exit( 1 );
    }
  ;
    //Print eigenvalues
    print_rmatrix( "zheev Eigenvalues", 1, n, wr, 1 );
  ;
    //Print eigenvectors
    print_matrix( "Eigenvectors (stored columnwise)", n, n, ah, lda );
  ;
    //Local arrays
    ldcmplex wc[N];
    ldcmplex ag[LDA*N] = {0};
    ldcmplex wgr[LDA*N] = {0};
    double2_t ag2[LDA*N] = {
      { 9.14,  0.00}, {-4.37, -9.22}, {-1.98, -1.72}, {-8.96, -9.50},
      {-4.37,  9.22}, {-3.35,  0.00}, { 2.25, -9.51}, { 2.57,  2.40},
      {-1.98,  1.72}, { 2.25,  9.51}, {-4.82,  0.00}, {-3.24,  2.04},
      {-8.96,  9.50}, { 2.57, -2.40}, {-3.24, -2.04}, { 8.44,  0.00},
    };
  ;

    printf("\n\n");

    //Executable statements
    set_matrix(n, ag, lda, ag2);
    printf( "LAPACKE_zgeev (row-major, high-level) Example Program Results\n" );
  ;
    //Print martix
    print_matrix( "Input Matrix", n, n, ag, lda );
  ;
    //Solve eigenproblem
    info = LAPACKE_zgeev( LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'N', 'V', n, ag, lda, wc, 0, lda, wgr, lda);
  ;
    //Check for convergence
    if( info > 0 ) {
            printf( "zgeev algorithm failed to compute eigenvalues.\n" );
            exit( 1 );
    }
  ;
    //Print eigenvalues
    print_matrix( "zgeev Eigenvalues", 1, n, wc, 1);
  ;
    //Print eigenvectors
    print_matrix( "Eigenvectors (stored columnwise)", n, n, wgr, lda );
    exit( 0 );
  }

//Auxiliary routine: printing a matrix
void print_matrix( char* desc, lint m, lint n, ldcmplex* a, lint lda ) {
        lint i, j;
        printf( "\n %s\n", desc );
        for( i = 0; i < m; i++ ) {
                for( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
                        printf( " (%6.2f,%6.2f)", creal(a[i*lda+j]), cimag(a[i*lda+j]) );
                printf( "\n" );
        }
}

//Auxiliary routine: printing a real matrix
void print_rmatrix( char* desc, lint m, lint n, double* a, lint lda ) {
        lint i, j;
        printf( "\n %s\n", desc );
        for( i = 0; i < m; i++ ) {
                for( j = 0; j < n; j++ ) printf( " %6.2f", a[i*lda+j] );
                printf( "\n" );
        }
}

//Auxiliary routine: set a complex matrix from a double[2] type matrix
void set_matrix(lapack_int n, lapack_complex_double* a, lapack_int lda, double2_t *a2) {
        lapack_int i, j;

        for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
                for( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
                        a[i*lda+j] = lapack_make_complex_double(a2[i*lda+j].v[0], a2[i*lda+j].v[1]);
        }
}
```

Build and run: `gcc sample.c -llapacke && ./a.out`. The output:

```
LAPACKE_zheev (row-major, high-level) Example Program Results

 Input Matrix
 (  9.14,  0.00) (  0.00,  0.00) (  0.00,  0.00) (  0.00,  0.00)
 ( -4.37,  9.22) ( -3.35,  0.00) (  0.00,  0.00) (  0.00,  0.00)
 ( -1.98,  1.72) (  2.25,  9.51) ( -4.82,  0.00) (  0.00,  0.00)
 ( -8.96,  9.50) (  2.57, -2.40) ( -3.24, -2.04) (  8.44,  0.00)

 zheev Eigenvalues
 -16.00  -6.76   6.67  25.51

 Eigenvectors (stored columnwise)
 (  0.34, -0.00) ( -0.55,  0.00) (  0.31,  0.00) ( -0.70,  0.00)
 (  0.44, -0.54) (  0.26,  0.18) (  0.45,  0.29) (  0.22, -0.28)
 ( -0.48, -0.37) ( -0.52, -0.02) ( -0.05,  0.57) (  0.15,  0.08)
 (  0.10, -0.12) ( -0.50,  0.28) ( -0.23, -0.48) (  0.34, -0.49)


LAPACKE_zgeev (row-major, high-level) Example Program Results

 Input Matrix
 (  9.14,  0.00) ( -4.37, -9.22) ( -1.98, -1.72) ( -8.96, -9.50)
 ( -4.37,  9.22) ( -3.35,  0.00) (  2.25, -9.51) (  2.57,  2.40)
 ( -1.98,  1.72) (  2.25,  9.51) ( -4.82,  0.00) ( -3.24,  2.04)
 ( -8.96,  9.50) (  2.57, -2.40) ( -3.24, -2.04) (  8.44,  0.00)

 zgeev Eigenvalues
 ( 25.51, -0.00) (-16.00, -0.00) ( -6.76, -0.00) (  6.67, -0.00)

 Eigenvectors (stored columnwise)
 (  0.70,  0.00) (  0.22,  0.27) (  0.48,  0.26) ( -0.03, -0.31)
 ( -0.22,  0.28) (  0.70,  0.00) ( -0.14, -0.29) (  0.24, -0.48)
 ( -0.15, -0.08) ( -0.01, -0.61) (  0.45,  0.27) (  0.58,  0.00)
 ( -0.34,  0.49) (  0.16, -0.00) (  0.58,  0.00) ( -0.46,  0.27)
```

As one notices, the eigenvalues and eigen vectors from both `ZHEEV` and `ZGEEV` are indeed the same, only their order is different. So it's importatnt to make sure the source matrix is properly formed, as the data eventually gets passed to Fortran by reference ('garbage-in -> garbage-out').